# does mongoose use multipe threads/processes/worker internally?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I was wondering, if mongoose uses its own processes/workers internally to handle multiple access to a MongoDB via one connection?

I could not find any information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the pool size of the Mongoose connection using:

```
    var uri = 'mongodb://localhost/test';
    mongoose.createConnection(uri, { server: { poolSize: 4 }});
```

Read 'Connection Pools' at http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html

Comment: Thanks. Do you know the internals? is a separate worker process used?

Comment: I know it's a bit late, but mongoose does not use a separate process or thread =]

Comment: What 's the default number of threads in the pool?